# AngularJS chained select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, model, linked-list

```
<select multiple ng-model="comp" ng-options="c.name for c in companies | unique: 'company'" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; float: left; margin-bottom: 20px"></select>

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="c in comp">
    <td>{{ c.id }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<select multiple ng-model="dep" ng-options="c.name for c in departments | filter: {company_id: comp.id}" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; float: left; margin-bottom: 20px"></select>
<select multiple ng-model="pos" ng-options="c.name for c in positions | unique: 'position' | filter: {department_id: dep.id}" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; float: left"></select>
```

Is what my code looks like, but it works only partially. If I loop it through `ng-repeat`, the `c.id` prints out fine, when I click on the company in the select box. Trouble is - it doesn't print out at other select boxes where I want to filter the results. What could be the cause of that?

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/853/

Comment: Can you demonstrate it in Fiddle? take template here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/852/

Comment: @MaximShoustin ok here goes http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/853/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that `comp` is a list of (selected) companies, not a single company. While the table works fine (ng-repeat iterates over the table), the filter fails since `comp.id` evaluates to `undefined`.

This can be solved by changing our filter to be as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="fessCntrl">
    <select multiple ng-model="comp" ng-options="c.name for c in companies | unique: 'company'" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; float: left; margin-bottom: 20px"></select>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="c in comp">
            <td>{{ c.id }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <pre>{{ comp }}</pre>
    <select multiple ng-model="dep" ng-options="c.name for c in departments | filter:sameId(comp, 'company_id')" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; float: left; margin-bottom: 20px"></select>
    <select multiple ng-model="pos" 
        ng-options="c.name for c in positions | unique: 'position' | filter:sameId(dep, 'department_id')"                
        style="width: 100%; height: 200px; float: left"></select>
</div>
```

For the code to work, `sameId` has to be defined on the scope of `fessCntrl`.

```
$scope.sameId = function(grouping, object_id_field_name) {
    return function(object) {
        var obj_id = object[object_id_field_name];
        for (var i = 0; i < grouping.length; i++) {
            if (grouping[i].id == obj_id)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```